# How to label specific groups (using the subset command) within a data set and then obtain scatter plot for each one?

Tags: r, subset, scatter-plot

3. A research group at the Yellowstone National Park suggested creating three sub-groups of the data. Group 1: waiting < 70 and duration ≥ 3; Group 2: waiting ≥ 70 and duration ≥ 3; Group 3: waiting ≥ 70 and duration < 3. Create these three sub-groups of data. (Use the subset command. Group1 < subset(geyser, geyser$waiting < 70 & geyser$duration >= 3, for example.)

---I am having issues defining each group (1,2,3) as its own so I can recall that specific group as a scatter plot on its own.

here is my code for the first, second, and third group

```
subset(geyser, geyser$waiting < 70 & geyser$duration >= 3)
subset(geyser, geyser$waiting >= 70 & geyser$duration >= 3)
subset(geyser, geyser$waiting >= 70 & geyser$duration < 3)
```

so i use the plot function but how do only plot group 1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need the `$` in `subset()`. Just `subset(geyser, waiting < 70, duration >= 3)` will work.

Comment: You've already defined group one as your first subset. Can't you just plot the first subset?